# How can I write a wait_for_ajax call in selenium where the web page uses XMLHttpRequest based AJAX calls?

Tags: ajax, selenium, xmlhttprequest

I have a select box which calls a XMLHttpRequest based AJAX call to populate another select box.
I want selenium to wait till the select box is populated. I have to wait for XMLHttpRequest's readyState variable to have value 4 which means data populated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java: You could wait for the readyState change like this:

```
    int tryCount = 0;
    boolean desiredResponseReceived = false;
    while (desiredResponseReceived == false && tryCount < 20) {
        String readyState = (String) js.executeScript("return xhr.readyState;");
        if (readyState.equals("4")) {
            desiredResponseReceived = true;
        }
        else {
            Thread.sleep(250);
            tryCount++;
        }
    }

    if (desiredResponseReceived == false) {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

One problem with looking for the ready state is, the page could be making more than one XMLHttpRequest. And you won't know which one is which. Even if you check for it immediately after clicking the relevant button (for example) even that could fire off multiple requests. And there's no telling which would return first.

Another option in your case might be to instead wait for the `options` in the `select` box to change. So in the code above, you might replace

```
String readyState = (String) js.executeScript("return xhr.readyState;");
     if (readyState.equals("4")) {
```

with

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
     if (options.size() > 1) {
```

Or if you don't know what minimum number of `options` to expect, you could test that an `option` with a particular `attribute` is in the `List`. Or something like that.